# Curve rectangle to follow a path

Tags: css, svg

It is possible with divs, shapes or svgs to curve an item to follow the curve of the path.

It's just an example, but imagine the rectangles curving on the edges, right now it's just had turn 90deg from one frame to another

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">      <title>frame</title><style>
        main {
          width: 100vw;height: 100vh;position: absolute;
        }
        div {
          display: none;position: absolute;will-change: offset-distance;width: 200px;
          height: 40px;background: hsl(313,100%,50%);offset-anchor: top;
          offset-rotate: auto;offset-path: path('M 0 0 L 600 0 L 600 400 L 0 400 L 0 0'); 
        }
        
        div:nth-of-type(4n+2) {background: hsl(343,100%,50%)}
        div:nth-of-type(4n+3) {background: hsl(13,100%,50%)}
        div:nth-of-type(4n+4) {background: rgb(37, 16, 226)}
        body {margin: 0;padding: 0;}            
        svg, aside {    display: none;}
        div {    display: block;    }
        * {box-sizing: border-box;}         
        
        </style>
</head>    <body>    <main><div></div>      <div></div>     <div></div>     <div></div>     <div></div><div></div>    </main>
<script>
    var rateRange = document.getElementById('playback-rate');
    var shapers = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('div'));
    var DURATION = 200000;
    var animations = [];

    shapers.forEach(function(s, i) {
        var animation = s.animate([
        {offsetDistance: 0},
        {offsetDistance: '100%'}
        ], {
            duration: DURATION,
            delay: -i / shapers.length * DURATION,
            iterations: Infinity
        });
        animations.push(animation);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: cool work.looks great.

Comment: it's not my code, I found online and i'm using to learn, original: https://danielcwilson.com/blog/2020/01/motion-path-quirks/

Comment: @Mateus Silva can you please somehow show the desired output? You can link to any gif or video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an svg solution. I'm using 4 overlapping paths where the stroke-dasharray is like this: `stroke-dasharray: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 242` If you are summing the dashes and the gaps the total is 260.

Also `stroke-linecap: round` When the dashes are very near one of the other `stroke-linecap: round` make them overlapping giving the apparence of a continuos line.

The total length of the path is also 260.  I'm animating the `stroke.dashoffset` property of the path.

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 10;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 242;
  animation: dash 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: -260;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 70" >

  <path id="pth" stroke="red" d="M10,10L90,10L90,60L10,60z" />

  <path stroke="blue" d="M70,10L90,10L90,60L10,60L10,10z" />

  <path stroke="green" d="M90,60L10,60L10,10L90,10z" />

  <path stroke="orange" d="M30,60L10,60L10,10L90,10L90,60z" />

</svg>
```

#### UPDATE

In order to avoid the flickering at the corners I'm changing the rectangular paths to paths with rounded corners. T make it clear what I mean by this I'm adding an extra path: the `#track`.

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 10;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 225;
  animation: dash 5s linear infinite;
}

#track {
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke-dasharray: 245 0;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: -245;
  }
}

svg {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 70">

  <path id="pth" stroke="red" d="M27.000,10.000 Q37,10 47.000,10.000L80.000,10.000 Q90,10 90.000,20.000L90.000,50.000 Q90,60 80.000,60.000L20.000,60.000 Q10,60 10.000,50.000L10.000,20.000 Q10,10 20.000,10.000Z" />

  <path stroke="blue" d="M90.000,27.000 Q90,37 90.000,47.000L90.000,50.000 Q90,60 80.000,60.000L20.000,60.000 Q10,60 10.000,50.000L10.000,20.000 Q10,10 20.000,10.000L80.000,10.000 Q90,10 90.000,20.000Z" />


  <path stroke="green" d="M73.000,60.000 Q63,60 53.000,60.000L20.000,60.000 Q10,60 10.000,50.000L10.000,20.000 Q10,10 20.000,10.000L80.000,10.000 Q90,10 90.000,20.000L90.000,50.000 Q90,60 80.000,60.000Z" />

  <path stroke="orange" d="M10.000,45.000 Q10,35 10.000,25.000L10.000,20.000 Q10,10 20.000,10.000L80.000,10.000 Q90,10 90.000,20.000L90.000,50.000 Q90,60 80.000,60.000L20.000,60.000 Q10,60 10.000,50.000Z" />
  
  
  <path id="track" d="M90.000,27.000 Q90,37 90.000,47.000L90.000,50.000 Q90,60 80.000,60.000L20.000,60.000 Q10,60 10.000,50.000L10.000,20.000 Q10,10 20.000,10.000L80.000,10.000 Q90,10 90.000,20.000Z" stroke="black" />

</svg>
```

Comment: my god, you nailed. css is amazing.

Comment: @enxaneta Thanks enxaneta! Smart decision I really liked